# Understanding ldd output

Tags: linker, ldd

How does `ldd` knows it's depending on `libc.so.6` ,not `libc.so.5` or `libc.so.7`?

```
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000034f4000000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000034f3c00000)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is recorded inside application binary itself (specified at compile time, more exactly at link step, done with `ld`):

```
$ readelf -d /bin/echo

Dynamic section at offset 0x5f1c contains 21 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
...
```

(there are some additional columns for how elf does store information in dynamic section. but you can see that libc.so.6 is hardcoded with `.6` suffix because of [SONAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname))

or even without any knowledge of ELF file format:

```
$ strings /bin/echo |grep libc.so
libc.so.6
```

To find, how does linker find a library (it is done at final step of compilation), use `gcc` option `-Wl,--verbose` (this asks gcc to pass option `--verbose` to `ld`):

```
$ gcc a.c -Wl,--verbose

...
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/libc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/libc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/libc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/libc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/../../../libc.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/../../../libc.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.4/../../../libc.so
attempt to open /lib/libc.so.6 succeeded
/lib/libc.so.6
```

Linker doesn't know anything about `.digit` suffix, it just iterate over all library  search directories trying to open `libLIBNAME.so` and `libLIBNAME.a`, where LIBNAME is a string after `-l` option. ( `-lc` option is added by default).

First success is `/usr/lib/libc.so` which itself is not a library, but a linker script (text file). Here is content from typical `libc.so` script:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/libc.so
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
GROUP ( /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ) )
```

So, script `/usr/lib/libc.so` is found earlier than actual library, and this script says, what file will be linked, `libc.so.6` in this case.

In more common case, `lib___.so` is symlink to some version like `lib___.so.3.4.5` and there is SONAME field filled in `lib___.so.3.4.5` which says to `ld` link not to `lib___.so` but to `lib___.so.3.4` which is another symlink to `lib___.so.3.4.5`. The `.3.4` name will be recorded in NEEDED field of binary.

Comment: What does `0x00000001 (NEEDED)` mean?

Comment: Is it true that `ldconfig` will link `libc.so.6` to the latest version of `libc.so.6.x` ,and link `lib.so` to the latest version of `libc.so.x`? And suppose `lib.so` links to `lib.so.7`,then binary generated by `gcc -l lib.so ...` will depend on `lib.so.7`,right?

Comment: +1 for editing your answer to contain so much useful information. This is a classic SO post. Thanks.

Comment: @osgx, how did you open the linker script in the first place?

Comment: @compile-fan, on my machine `/usr/lib/libc.so` was a text file, so I opened it with cat. On our machine, or with another library you should run `gcc -Wl,--verbose` to get how linker search for lib, and where are linker scripts.

Comment: @compile-fan, can you post (add as text in your question edit) output of `gcc -Wl,--verbose helloworld.c` ? What Linux do you have?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.dynamic.html#dynamic_section

Has the meaning of each dynamic tags. The 1 indicates it is a DT_NEEDED tag meaning in this case the

```
typedef struct {
    Elf32_Sword d_tag;
    union {
        Elf32_Word  d_val;
        Elf32_Addr  d_ptr;
    } d_un;
} Elf32_Dyn;
```

structure has d_val union valid and look up at an offset specified by thi union member in DT_STRTAB table to find the name of library that this binary/SO depends on.